# Generate a table row with <td> values from DB PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a dynamically made table that will display multiple drop down lists within each row with previously selected values that are stored within a DB.

Currently I am stuck on just displaying the proper values within each `<td>`.

```
//$query..               
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

echo"<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Component</th>
        <th>Component Type</th>
        <th>Component Thickness</th>
        </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { //while I have rows..

    //add column values to an array
    $facSecComponentID[] = $row['facility_section_components_id'];
    $facSecComponent[] = $row['roof_component_id'];
    $facSecComponentType[] = $row['roof_component_type_id'];
    $facSecComponentThickness[] = $row['component_thickness'];

    //try to loop through each index of each row and get the DB value..
    //eventually use this value to assign a selected index within the drop down list
    foreach ($row as $componentIndex => $selectedComponent) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $facSecComponent[$selectedComponent] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $facSecComponentType[$selectedComponent] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $facSecComponentThickness[$selectedComponent] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

I can't get the values I need here to display properly, I have also tried to do something like: `"<td>" . $componentIndex[$selectedComponent] . "</td>";` which didn't help.

I keep getting undefined index errors or all fields being a single value.

Let me know if anything is unclear or needs further explanation and I will try to make my question more clear.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Complete your While loop. Do a separate loop and iterate your Array items. I think you're doing too much in the While loop.

Comment: Also you are not creating indexes for the Arrays. So instead of a `foreach` use a `for` loop and call the elements by number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$facSecComponentID = array();
$facSecComponent = array();
$facSecComponentType = array();
$facSecComponentThickness = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $facSecComponentID[] = $row['facility_section_components_id'];
    $facSecComponent[] = $row['roof_component_id'];
    $facSecComponentType[] = $row['roof_component_type_id'];
    $facSecComponentThickness[] = $row['component_thickness'];
}

$numItems = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i=0;$i<$numItems;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$facSecComponent[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$facSecComponentType[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$facSecComponentThickness[$i]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked exactly how I needed it too, I was definitely over complicating things.

Comment: Great! You were in the right area. Just needed to separate the activities a little.

Answer (score -2):

It's better if you concatenate a string like

```
$this->Table ="<table>";
while($MyRow = mysqli_fetch_array($fect)){
$this->Table .="<tr><td>".$MyRow['data']."</td></tr>";

}
$this->Table .="</table>";

return $this->Table ;
```

Comment: I am not asking how to concat a string, thanks though.

Comment: I said that it's more easly if you concat the table in a string because you can manipulate it.

Comment: Does that answer the question I am asking?

Comment: Yup, you can return it, if you wan't to use Jquery Ajax you can insert with .html() or the <tr> with append